# Arduino Previous and Current Sensor Variables

Tags: arduino, sensors, arduino-uno

I have an Arduino UNO hooked up to an ultrasonic rangefinder which reads into the variable `distance`. However, I need to, on one second intervals, read the current distance and then store the previous distance (from the last second). I also need to be able to use these variables (`Dprev` and `Dcurr`) other places in my code.

I am presuming I need to put it into some sort of `while` loop that iterates every second, but I don't know how to put it all together, or use time in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is simple. Two global variables for storing distance and two fases. `Arduino`use the function `setup` at the begining of execution, then loop infinite the function `loop`. So in `setup`, just initialize variables and in `loop` take distances.

```
#define trigPin 13
#define echoPin 12

long duration, distance, distance_prev;
void setup() {
  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
  duration = 0;
  distance = 0;
  distance_prev= 0;
}

void loop() {

  distance_prev = distance;

  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW); //Send ultrasonic pulse

  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);//Time for ultrasonic pulse to go and back
  distance = (duration/2) / 29.1;//Conversion to cm

  /*CODE USING DISTANCES HERE*/

  delay(1000); //One second delay 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I have been so stuck